# What is boundary of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: general-topology

What is boundary of $\mathbb{C}$? or $\partial \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: In its standard topology and regarding it as a subset of itself, it is both open and closed, so its closure minus its interior is the empty set.

Comment: In other words, the set of all complex numbers does not have a boundary!

Answer (score 5):

The concept of [*boundary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) applies to a subspace of a topological space, not to the space itself. As [Ian pointed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649116/what-is-boundary-of-mathbbc/1649137#comment3363358_1649116), the boundary of a space considering it as a subspace of itself it empty.

A couple of examples:

- $\partial\mathbb{C} = \varnothing$ if we think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}$.
- If we embed $\mathbb{C}$ into the Riemann sphere, then $\partial\mathbb{C}$ will be the point at infinity.
- If we embed $\mathbb{C}$ into the two-dimensional projective plane, $\partial\mathbb{C}$ will be the line at infinity.
- We can even embed $\mathbb{C}$ as a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Here, the boundary of $\mathbb{C}$ will be all of $\mathbb{C}$.

As you can see, the boundary can vary a lot depending on the containing space.

---

From another point of view, $\mathbb{C}$ can be seen as a two-dimensional real [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) or a one-dimensional complex manifold. In this cases, the boundary is well-defined, and is empty.